# Divide a task into subtasks and assign to thread pool

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to read an image manipulate the pixel data(Gaussian or any other) and write the pixels to a new image.Since the images come in big sizes(>1GB and may even be >20 GB),I read them one row at at time with whole width.So it becomes block wise reading.Now my work requires a faster mechanism to do the whole process.Will thread pool work as an effective solution.I cannot use other libraries for image processing,we have an engine built for that.

I have referred to a sample threadpool sample from code project and I am reading the image in the thread's run function but I am really not sure how it works.

```
HRESULT hRes = m_ObjPool.Init(10, 100); //spawning the thread
void CThreadObject::Run(CThreadPoolThreadCallback &pool)
{
    //I read and write my image here using for loop
    for(int i=0;i<nImageHeight;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<nImageWidth;j++)
        {
            Engine.ReadImage(params);
        }
    }
 }
```

What I was trying to achieve here is how do I give tasks to thread pool if the image is segmented into 10 or 100 parts(depending on the image size and block size).

Comment: That sounds like reading the image data is the bottleneck. In that case, using a concurrent solution is going to be as fast as a single-threaded approach, at best, and usually slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Just one thing,My doubt was related to image reading.Can it not be done concurrently?

Comment: Since you are already reading as fast as possible, spreading the task across different threads isn't going to speed anything up. If you need to increase read speed, you're going to have to invest in hardware (e.g. a faster SSD or NAS).